# How to use array of const with strings?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm having an issue with `array of const` in Delphi 11.3.

I have a function:

`MyFunc(test: array of const)`

When I call it with integers, I have no trouble getting them back as integers, eg:

`MyFunc([2,4,9,0)`

and `test[0]` etc works as expected.

However, if I pass in a string, eg:

`MyFunc(['test',9])`

I cannot get the string back.
The `vType` returns 17, `_Reserved1`.

I've looked at as many places as I can, but I'm stuck. Can somebody explain this, and
tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `_Reserved1` has a numerical value of 1 (hence its name), not 17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern Delphi versions, the default string type is [`UnicodeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString).

Now, the [`TVarRec`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TVarRec) documentation does not mention any `vType` for `UnicodeString`, but in the `System` unit there is a `vtUnicodeString` constant declared, and it has the value of `17`.

That same constant is being used in the `TVarRec` record for detecting `UnicodeString`.

So, it seems that documentation on `TVarRec` is not up to date.

---

You might be wondering why `vtString` isn't returned in your case. Well, `vtString` is actually intended for [`ShortString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ShortString), which is to be deprecated, or should I say is already deprecated, for any mobile platforms.

You could also perform the next test scenario and you will see which values are returned for each string type:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var S1: ShortString;
    S2: AnsiString;
    S3: UnicodeString;
    S4: WideString;
    S5: String;
begin
  S1 := 'ShortString';
  S2 := 'AnsiString';
  S3 := 'UnicodeString';
  S4 := 'WideString';
  S5 := 'String';
  MyFunc([S1,S2,S3,S4,S5]);
end;
```

Comment: I've always "_w**o**ndered_" if your name "_war_ior_" is intentional...

Comment: Thanks! That explains it perfectly. :)

Comment: @AmigoJack You mean why it is misspelled with only one R in Warrior? Well the reason fir this actually originates from about 20 years or so ago when I was creating my first E-Mail on yahoo mail service because it had a character limit for nickname. So basically I had to drop one R in order to fit the limitation. And even thou today's systems no longer impose such limit I kept my original nickname for consistency. And yes English is not my natural language which is why I sometimes misspell some words  or have poor or even wrong choice of words.

Comment: @AmigoJack As a veteran Delphi developer would you mind reporting this issue if outdated documentation to Embaracadero. Last time I reported similar issue on outdated documentation in 2014 [RSP-9694)](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9694) it got simply closed because no one even touched it for so long. Maybe you will have better luck.

Comment: @SilverWarior the `vtUnicodeString` constant is mentioned in the `System` documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System#Constants: "*vtUnicodeString: Integer = $11;*" Hex `$11` is decimal `17`

Comment: I have opened a new Quality Portal ticket for the missing documentation: [RSP-44043](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-44043)